# Install network-manager on Ubuntu Server

Tags: server, package-management, software-installation, network-manager

How to install NetworkManager on Ubuntu Server without dependencies, which wants X11 and Gnome/Unity related stuff?

```
# apt-cache show network-manager
Package: network-manager
Architecture: amd64
Version: 1.2.6-0ubuntu0.16.04.2
Priority: optional
Section: net
Origin: Ubuntu
Maintainer: Ubuntu Core Dev Team <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
Original-Maintainer: Utopia Maintenance Team <pkg-utopia-maintainers@lists.alioth.debian.org>
Bugs: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+filebug
Installed-Size: 9592
Depends: libbluetooth3 (>= 4.91), libc6 (>= 2.17), libglib2.0-0 (>= 2.39.4), libgnutls30 (>= 3.4.0), libgudev-1.0-0 (>= 165), libmm-glib0 (>= 1.0.0), libndp0 (>= 1.2), libnewt0.52, libnl-3-200 (>= 3.2.7), libnm0 (>= 1.1.93), libpolkit-agent-1-0 (>= 0.99), libpolkit-gobject-1-0 (>= 0.104), libreadline6 (>= 6.0), libsoup2.4-1 (>= 2.40), libsystemd0, libuuid1 (>= 2.16), init-system-helpers (>= 1.18~), lsb-base (>= 4.1+Debian11ubuntu7), dnsmasq-base, wpasupplicant (>= 0.7.3-1), dbus (>= 1.1.2), udev, adduser, isc-dhcp-client (>= 4.3.1-5ubuntu1), libpam-systemd, policykit-1
Recommends: ppp (>= 2.4.6), iptables, modemmanager, crda, iputils-arping, network-manager-pptp, network-manager-gnome | plasma-widget-networkmanagement | plasma-nm
Suggests: avahi-autoipd, python
Conflicts: connman
Breaks: network-manager-gnome (<< 0.9), network-manager-kde (<< 1:0.9), network-manager-openconnect (<< 0.9), network-manager-openvpn (<< 0.9), network-manager-pptp (<< 0.9), network-manager-vpnc (<< 0.9), plasma-widget-networkmanagement (<< 0.9~), ppp (<< 2.4.6)
Filename: pool/main/n/network-manager/network-manager_1.2.6-0ubuntu0.16.04.2_amd64.deb
Size: 1971838
MD5sum: f998e2f528fa9b355d2e2a5b01c1082e
SHA1: 5fb2e5d77fa8e40c601885fbbd01cb857f914c0d
SHA256: 0396212ef949e9898cfeae0f10ef9afb626cdce8ab7f4b065337787a1ba1076f
Homepage: https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/NetworkManager
Description-en: network management framework (daemon and userspace tools)
 NetworkManager is a system network service that manages your network devices
 and connections, attempting to keep active network connectivity when
 available. It manages ethernet, WiFi, mobile broadband (WWAN), and PPPoE
 devices, and provides VPN integration with a variety of different VPN
 services.
 .
 This package provides the userspace daemons and a command line interface to
 interact with NetworkManager.
 .
 Optional dependencies:
  * ppp: Required for establishing dial-up connections (e.g. via GSM).
  * avahi-autoipd: Used for IPv4LL, a protocol for automatic Link-Local IP
    address configuration.
Description-md5: 8f6f8b56b77097ec1e2134d2c9189882
Task: ubuntu-desktop, ubuntu-usb, kubuntu-desktop, kubuntu-full, edubuntu-desktop, edubuntu-usb, xubuntu-core, xubuntu-desktop, mythbuntu-frontend, mythbuntu-desktop, mythbuntu-backend-slave, mythbuntu-backend-master, lubuntu-desktop, ubuntustudio-desktop-core, ubuntustudio-desktop, ubuntu-gnome-desktop, ubuntu-touch-core, ubuntu-touch, ubuntu-sdk, ubuntukylin-desktop, ubuntu-mate-core, ubuntu-mate-desktop, ubuntu-mate-cloudtop
Supported: 5y

Package: network-manager
Architecture: amd64
Version: 1.2.2-0ubuntu0.16.04.4
Priority: optional
Section: net
Origin: Ubuntu
Maintainer: Ubuntu Core Dev Team <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
Original-Maintainer: Utopia Maintenance Team <pkg-utopia-maintainers@lists.alioth.debian.org>
Bugs: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+filebug
Installed-Size: 9540
Depends: libbluetooth3 (>= 4.91), libc6 (>= 2.17), libglib2.0-0 (>= 2.39.4), libgnutls30 (>= 3.4.0), libgudev-1.0-0 (>= 165), libmm-glib0 (>= 1.0.0), libndp0 (>= 1.2), libnewt0.52, libnl-3-200 (>= 3.2.7), libnm0 (>= 1.1.93), libpolkit-agent-1-0 (>= 0.99), libpolkit-gobject-1-0 (>= 0.104), libreadline6 (>= 6.0), libsoup2.4-1 (>= 2.40), libsystemd0, libuuid1 (>= 2.16), init-system-helpers (>= 1.18~), lsb-base (>= 4.1+Debian11ubuntu7), dnsmasq-base, wpasupplicant (>= 0.7.3-1), dbus (>= 1.1.2), udev, adduser, isc-dhcp-client (>= 4.3.1-5ubuntu1), libpam-systemd, policykit-1
Recommends: ppp (>= 2.4.6), iptables, modemmanager, crda, iputils-arping, network-manager-pptp, network-manager-gnome | plasma-widget-networkmanagement | plasma-nm
Suggests: avahi-autoipd, python
Conflicts: connman
Breaks: network-manager-gnome (<< 0.9), network-manager-kde (<< 1:0.9), network-manager-openconnect (<< 0.9), network-manager-openvpn (<< 0.9), network-manager-pptp (<< 0.9), network-manager-vpnc (<< 0.9), plasma-widget-networkmanagement (<< 0.9~), ppp (<< 2.4.6)
Filename: pool/main/n/network-manager/network-manager_1.2.2-0ubuntu0.16.04.4_amd64.deb
Size: 1955182
MD5sum: 25585cbc57a65bb515e739d2687b6ccb
SHA1: 37c91afc29b5271a8c4e5a869eb98ff9404221c6
SHA256: 98a33b0eef06d1219fbf285746790b8c1cbfc84c1adde278240fcf569bd264c0
Homepage: https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/NetworkManager
Description-en: network management framework (daemon and userspace tools)
 NetworkManager is a system network service that manages your network devices
 and connections, attempting to keep active network connectivity when
 available. It manages ethernet, WiFi, mobile broadband (WWAN), and PPPoE
 devices, and provides VPN integration with a variety of different VPN
 services.
 .
 This package provides the userspace daemons and a command line interface to
 interact with NetworkManager.
 .
 Optional dependencies:
  * ppp: Required for establishing dial-up connections (e.g. via GSM).
  * avahi-autoipd: Used for IPv4LL, a protocol for automatic Link-Local IP
    address configuration.
Description-md5: 8f6f8b56b77097ec1e2134d2c9189882
Task: ubuntu-desktop, ubuntu-usb, kubuntu-desktop, kubuntu-full, edubuntu-desktop, edubuntu-usb, xubuntu-core, xubuntu-desktop, mythbuntu-frontend, mythbuntu-desktop, mythbuntu-backend-slave, mythbuntu-backend-master, lubuntu-desktop, ubuntustudio-desktop-core, ubuntustudio-desktop, ubuntu-gnome-desktop, ubuntu-touch-core, ubuntu-touch, ubuntu-sdk, ubuntukylin-desktop, ubuntu-mate-core, ubuntu-mate-desktop, ubuntu-mate-cloudtop
Supported: 5y

Package: network-manager
Priority: optional
Section: net
Installed-Size: 9524
Maintainer: Ubuntu Core Dev Team <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
Original-Maintainer: Utopia Maintenance Team <pkg-utopia-maintainers@lists.alioth.debian.org>
Architecture: amd64
Version: 1.1.93-0ubuntu4
Depends: libbluetooth3 (>= 4.91), libc6 (>= 2.17), libglib2.0-0 (>= 2.39.4), libgnutls30 (>= 3.4.0), libgudev-1.0-0 (>= 165), libmm-glib0 (>= 1.0.0), libndp0 (>= 1.2), libnewt0.52, libnl-3-200 (>= 3.2.7), libnm0 (>= 1.1.93), libpolkit-agent-1-0 (>= 0.99), libpolkit-gobject-1-0 (>= 0.104), libreadline6 (>= 6.0), libsoup2.4-1 (>= 2.40), libsystemd0, libuuid1 (>= 2.16), init-system-helpers (>= 1.18~), lsb-base (>= 4.1+Debian11ubuntu7), dnsmasq-base, wpasupplicant (>= 0.7.3-1), dbus (>= 1.1.2), udev, adduser, isc-dhcp-client (>= 4.3.1-5ubuntu1), libpam-systemd, policykit-1
Recommends: ppp (>= 2.4.6), iptables, modemmanager, crda, iputils-arping, network-manager-pptp, network-manager-gnome | plasma-widget-networkmanagement | plasma-nm
Suggests: avahi-autoipd, python
Conflicts: connman
Breaks: network-manager-gnome (<< 0.9), network-manager-kde (<< 1:0.9), network-manager-openconnect (<< 0.9), network-manager-openvpn (<< 0.9), network-manager-pptp (<< 0.9), network-manager-vpnc (<< 0.9), plasma-widget-networkmanagement (<< 0.9~), ppp (<< 2.4.6)
Filename: pool/main/n/network-manager/network-manager_1.1.93-0ubuntu4_amd64.deb
Size: 1946144
MD5sum: 2f31dc16a6a7c1efc05a16dec296604d
SHA1: 81969ff9ae213ade6bb08df9720dc5b458a17522
SHA256: 1bc253a4cd7ddff97fed13fe5b45752d66ef8fdce2b337acdfb3117ece6c2aab
Description-en: network management framework (daemon and userspace tools)
 NetworkManager is a system network service that manages your network devices
 and connections, attempting to keep active network connectivity when
 available. It manages ethernet, WiFi, mobile broadband (WWAN), and PPPoE
 devices, and provides VPN integration with a variety of different VPN
 services.
 .
 This package provides the userspace daemons and a command line interface to
 interact with NetworkManager.
 .
 Optional dependencies:
  * ppp: Required for establishing dial-up connections (e.g. via GSM).
  * avahi-autoipd: Used for IPv4LL, a protocol for automatic Link-Local IP
    address configuration.
Description-md5: 8f6f8b56b77097ec1e2134d2c9189882
Homepage: https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/NetworkManager
Bugs: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+filebug
Origin: Ubuntu
Supported: 5y
Task: ubuntu-desktop, ubuntu-usb, kubuntu-desktop, kubuntu-full, edubuntu-desktop, edubuntu-usb, xubuntu-core, xubuntu-desktop, mythbuntu-frontend, mythbuntu-desktop, mythbuntu-backend-slave, mythbuntu-backend-master, lubuntu-desktop, ubuntustudio-desktop-core, ubuntustudio-desktop, ubuntu-gnome-desktop, ubuntu-touch-core, ubuntu-touch, ubuntu-sdk, ubuntukylin-desktop, ubuntu-mate-core, ubuntu-mate-desktop, ubuntu-mate-cloudtop
```

I see `network-manager-gnome` package in "Reccomends" section. How to exclude GUI-dependencies from an installation?

```
# apt install network-manager
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  adwaita-icon-theme at-spi2-core colord colord-data dconf-gsettings-backend dconf-service fontconfig fontconfig-config fonts-dejavu-core gcr glib-networking glib-networking-common
  glib-networking-services gnome-keyring gsettings-desktop-schemas hicolor-icon-theme humanity-icon-theme indicator-application iputils-arping libappindicator3-1 libassuan0 libatk-bridge2.0-0
  libatk1.0-0 libatk1.0-data libatspi2.0-0 libbluetooth3 libboost-filesystem1.58.0 libboost-system1.58.0 libcairo-gobject2 libcairo2 libcapnp-0.5.3 libcolord2 libcolorhug2 libcroco3 libdatrie1
  libdbusmenu-glib4 libdbusmenu-gtk3-4 libdconf1 libdrm-amdgpu1 libdrm-intel1 libdrm-nouveau2 libdrm-radeon1 libegl1-mesa libepoxy0 libexif12 libfontconfig1 libgbm1 libgck-1-0 libgcr-3-common
  libgcr-base-3-1 libgcr-ui-3-1 libgd3 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-common libgl1-mesa-dri libglapi-mesa libgphoto2-6 libgphoto2-l10n libgphoto2-port12 libgraphite2-3 libgtk-3-0 libgtk-3-bin
  libgtk-3-common libgudev-1.0-0 libgusb2 libharfbuzz0b libieee1284-3 libindicator3-7 libjbig0 libjpeg-turbo8 libjpeg8 libjson-glib-1.0-0 libjson-glib-1.0-common liblcms2-2 libllvm5.0 libltdl7
  libmbim-glib4 libmbim-proxy libmirclient9 libmircommon7 libmircore1 libmirprotobuf3 libmm-glib0 libndp0 libnm0 libnma-common libnma0 libnotify4 libp11-kit-gnome-keyring libpam-gnome-keyring
  libpango-1.0-0 libpangocairo-1.0-0 libpangoft2-1.0-0 libpciaccess0 libpixman-1-0 libprotobuf-lite9v5 libproxy1v5 libqmi-glib1 libqmi-proxy librest-0.7-0 librsvg2-2 librsvg2-common libsane
  libsane-common libsecret-1-0 libsecret-common libsensors4 libsoup-gnome2.4-1 libsoup2.4-1 libthai-data libthai0 libtiff5 libtxc-dxtn-s2tc0 libvpx3 libwayland-client0 libwayland-cursor0
  libwayland-egl1-mesa libwayland-server0 libx11-xcb1 libxcb-dri2-0 libxcb-dri3-0 libxcb-present0 libxcb-render0 libxcb-shm0 libxcb-sync1 libxcb-xfixes0 libxcomposite1 libxcursor1 libxdamage1 libxfixes3
  libxi6 libxinerama1 libxkbcommon0 libxpm4 libxrandr2 libxrender1 libxshmfence1 libxtst6 mobile-broadband-provider-info modemmanager network-manager-gnome network-manager-pptp notification-daemon
  p11-kit p11-kit-modules pinentry-gnome3 policykit-1-gnome pptp-linux ubuntu-mono usb-modeswitch usb-modeswitch-data wpasupplicant x11-common
Suggested packages:
  colord-sensor-argyll libgd-tools gphoto2 gvfs liblcms2-utils librsvg2-bin avahi-daemon hplip libsane-extras sane-utils lm-sensors avahi-autoipd network-manager-openconnect-gnome
  network-manager-openvpn-gnome network-manager-vpnc-gnome network-manager-pptp-gnome pinentry-doc comgt wvdial wpagui libengine-pkcs11-openssl
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  adwaita-icon-theme at-spi2-core colord colord-data dconf-gsettings-backend dconf-service fontconfig fontconfig-config fonts-dejavu-core gcr glib-networking glib-networking-common
  glib-networking-services gnome-keyring gsettings-desktop-schemas hicolor-icon-theme humanity-icon-theme indicator-application iputils-arping libappindicator3-1 libassuan0 libatk-bridge2.0-0
  libatk1.0-0 libatk1.0-data libatspi2.0-0 libbluetooth3 libboost-filesystem1.58.0 libboost-system1.58.0 libcairo-gobject2 libcairo2 libcapnp-0.5.3 libcolord2 libcolorhug2 libcroco3 libdatrie1
  libdbusmenu-glib4 libdbusmenu-gtk3-4 libdconf1 libdrm-amdgpu1 libdrm-intel1 libdrm-nouveau2 libdrm-radeon1 libegl1-mesa libepoxy0 libexif12 libfontconfig1 libgbm1 libgck-1-0 libgcr-3-common
  libgcr-base-3-1 libgcr-ui-3-1 libgd3 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-common libgl1-mesa-dri libglapi-mesa libgphoto2-6 libgphoto2-l10n libgphoto2-port12 libgraphite2-3 libgtk-3-0 libgtk-3-bin
  libgtk-3-common libgudev-1.0-0 libgusb2 libharfbuzz0b libieee1284-3 libindicator3-7 libjbig0 libjpeg-turbo8 libjpeg8 libjson-glib-1.0-0 libjson-glib-1.0-common liblcms2-2 libllvm5.0 libltdl7
  libmbim-glib4 libmbim-proxy libmirclient9 libmircommon7 libmircore1 libmirprotobuf3 libmm-glib0 libndp0 libnm0 libnma-common libnma0 libnotify4 libp11-kit-gnome-keyring libpam-gnome-keyring
  libpango-1.0-0 libpangocairo-1.0-0 libpangoft2-1.0-0 libpciaccess0 libpixman-1-0 libprotobuf-lite9v5 libproxy1v5 libqmi-glib1 libqmi-proxy librest-0.7-0 librsvg2-2 librsvg2-common libsane
  libsane-common libsecret-1-0 libsecret-common libsensors4 libsoup-gnome2.4-1 libsoup2.4-1 libthai-data libthai0 libtiff5 libtxc-dxtn-s2tc0 libvpx3 libwayland-client0 libwayland-cursor0
  libwayland-egl1-mesa libwayland-server0 libx11-xcb1 libxcb-dri2-0 libxcb-dri3-0 libxcb-present0 libxcb-render0 libxcb-shm0 libxcb-sync1 libxcb-xfixes0 libxcomposite1 libxcursor1 libxdamage1 libxfixes3
  libxi6 libxinerama1 libxkbcommon0 libxpm4 libxrandr2 libxrender1 libxshmfence1 libxtst6 mobile-broadband-provider-info modemmanager network-manager network-manager-gnome network-manager-pptp
  notification-daemon p11-kit p11-kit-modules pinentry-gnome3 policykit-1-gnome pptp-linux ubuntu-mono usb-modeswitch usb-modeswitch-data wpasupplicant x11-common
0 upgraded, 154 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 44.8 MB of archives.
After this operation, 315 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] ^C
```

Comment: https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/network-manager says `network-manager-gnome` is recommended. That's probably bringing in all those dependencies.

Comment: Thank you. `--no-install-recommends` solves the problem.